# Define header file Macros at compile using Make, and recompile source files with those updated Macros

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am new to makefiles and am struggling a little bit to get things to work how I want.

I have a header file with some structs and a bunch of macros that I have sitting in #ifndef statements so that they have a default value if they're not defined on the command line.

I have three .c files that all include this header to make use of these macros.

In my makefile, I need to be able to compile all my source files, which have the header file as a dependent.

What I would like to be able to do is when I run make, if I include new values for those macros, that the header file is updated, and this triggers the source files to also be recompiled so that they include the new values.

I don't know if this is the correct way to go about it.  The issue I am trying to avoid is if I pass these new values, but say only one of these source files recompile because make only identifies it as having been changed, and therefore different values are being used across the three programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like to be able to do is when I run make, if I include new values for those macros, that the header file is updated, and this triggers the source files to also be recompiled so that they include the new values.

And how do you suppose that `make` would recognize that the macro definitions in use have changed?  It cannot very easily compare the definitions themselves to values as-of previous runs.

What `make` *can* do pretty easily is compare the timestamp of the file wherein the macro definitions are recorded to the timestamps of the object files.  It can do that by making the former file a prerequisite for each of the latter files.

The file containing the macro definitions might be the makefile itself or some file `include`d into it.  If you use the makefile itself then you will sometimes get recompilations for reasons other than the macro definitions having changed, but many of those reasons will in fact be *good* reasons.  The object files and binaries have a *bona fide* dependency on the instructions used to build them.

So you might have something along these lines:

```
SOURCES = larry.c curly.c moe.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
DEFINES = -DOPTION1=1 -DOPTION2=0 -DOPTION3=1


prog: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c stooges.h Makefile
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $(DEFINES) $<
```

It would possible to instead use a similar procedure update the timestamp of the header file, thus forcing recompilation indirectly, but that's synthetic.  I recommend expressing the true dependencies instead.

**OR**, for a single-developer project, it would probably be feasible to just make it a developer responsibility to manually perform a clean build after performing makefile updates that require it.  That scales poorly as you add developers, though.

Comment: Thanks.  To clarify further I've never written a makefile in my life.  Uni has asked us to for an assignment and required that the macros be able to be changed at compile time using preprocessor directives.  I'll add that they've taught us nothing about make.

It just seems to me that what I'm trying to do is very arbitrary, and I don't know how else to go about it when I'm constrained by the assignment requirements

Comment: @DavidWebb, from my perspective it is natural, not at all arbitrary, that the built files have a dependency on the instructions and parameters used to build them. Not all makefiles use the approach I have described to model such dependencies, but plenty do.

Comment: What I know does work, is just passing all my variables to CPPFLAGS like so:
```make CPPFLAGS="-DOPTION0=1 -DOPTION1=3"```
But I believe I would have to run make clean if I wanted them all to recompile with new options?

Comment: @DavidWebb, if there is no persistent record of the compilation options, then there is no way to determine whether they have changed from one build to another.  That is the case when you use specify build options via `make` command-line options, unless you go to rather a lot of trouble in your makefile to arrange otherwise.  If you want there to be a persistent record, then the cleanest thing to do is to make it a *functional* persistent record by incorporating it into the makeflle.

Comment: Or if you want to continue to specify build flags via `make` command-line options then the easiest way to accommodate it would be by performing a clean build every time.

Comment: I'd say that this _bona fide_ is a billion dollar mistake no one has challenged yet. What @DavidWebb is saying supports this: proper config management isn't even a concern in CS education, and this blind side is never corrected in the job. Quite the contrary, many build systems perpetuate the stance that its ok as soon as it builds, no matter how it builds.

Comment: What I've done is if the "client" wants to reconfigure variables, they run make clean and then run make and specify the variables through CPPFLAGS.  It works but it's not exactly user friendly, and in development is annoying because I can't just change a variable and expect it to recompile all of the programs.  So I'm not persisting the values, but it works nonetheless